# Como clasificar error en c

Tags: c

Tengo la función `int rmdir()` y sabiendo que cuando devuelve -1 significa que hubo un error, no se cómo clasificar estos errores en ifs como en este ejemplo en esta función para borrar directorios en el shell:

```
int borrar(char *tokens[], int ntokens, list *history){ 
     for(int i=1; i<ntokens; i++){ //tokens[i]=NULL
          int a = remove(tokens[i]);//devuelve 0 si borro, tokens[i] nombre del file
          int b = rmdir(tokens[i]);//devuelve 0 si borro, tokens[i] nombre del directory
          if(a!=0 && b!=0){
               //if(/*TIPO ERROR ENOTEMPTY*/){
                    printf("Imposible borrar %s: No such file or directory\n",tokens[i]);
               //}else printf("Imposible borrar %s: Directory not empty\n");
          }else if(a==0){
               remove(tokens[i]);
          }else rmdir(tokens[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Por que expresión debo cambiar `/*TIPO ERROR ENOTEMPTY*/` para clasificar el error `EEXIST` de la pagina de la función [`rmdir()`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/r/rmdir.html)?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, en vez de hacerlo a lo bruto, lo primero que tendrías que identificar es qué es lo que intentas borrar, si es un directorio o un archivo:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sb;
if (stat(tokens[i], &sb) == 0)
{
    if (S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
    {
        // Intentamos borrar un directorio
    }
    else if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode))
    {
        // Intentamos borrar un archivo
    }
    else
    {
        // Intentamos borrar otra cosa (una unidad, un enlace simbólico ...)
    }
}
else
{
    // No existe el archivo o directorio (o se ha producido otro error)
}
```

Esto permite mostrar mensajes adecuados para cada situación.

Ahora ya podemos también ofrecer una solución personalizada para cada caso:

```
if (S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
{
    if (rmdir(tokens[i]) != 0)
    {
        // El directorio no ha podido ser eliminado ¿Por qué?
    }
}
else if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode))
{
    if (remove(tokens[i]) != 0)
    {
        // No se ha podido borrar el archivo ¿Por qué?
    }
}
else
{
    // Intentamos borrar otra cosa (una unidad, un enlace simbólico ...)
}
```

Ahora bien, cómo podemos identificar el motivo concreto por el que no hemos podido ejecutar esas acciones, bueno, si revisamos la documentación de estas funciones vemos que **todas** actualizan la variable `errno`, almacenando en dicha variable el código del error. Podemos obtener la descripción asociada a dicho valor mediante la función `strerror`:

```
#include <errno.h>

if (rmdir(tokens[i]) != 0)
{
    puts(strerror(errno));
}
```

También puedes hacerte tu propio `switch`, coger los códigos que te interesen y mostrar mensajes personalizados para cada caso (y uno más genérico para cuando se produzca un error de los que no has contemplado:

```
switch(errno)
{
    case EACCES:
        puts("Permiso denegado\n");
        break;

    case ENOTEMPTY:
        puts("El directorio no esta vacio\n");
        break;
    
    /* ... */
}
```

Y ya recapitulando ... ¿Por qué insisto en hacerlo así pese a que el código es más largo? Básicamente porque en `errno` se almacenará el código de error de la **última** operación, es decir, si intentas borrar un archivo no podrás saber qué ha pasado al llamar a `remove` porque `rmdir` habrá machacado el código de error.